# JQuery.ajax в обработчик success передать свою анонимную функцию

Tags: jquery, callback, ajax, javascript, замыкания

Проблема что данные не попадают в succesCallback.call(resp), где resp - ответ от сервера(хотя ответ приходит)
Помогите ,может эту проблему можно решить используя замыкания или еще что-то.Не зпрашивайте "зачем нужно" - долго обяъснять.

```
    function processRequest(data,succesCallback){
   if (typeof(data) !== "object") throw new Error('data must be in JSON format !');
   if (typeof(succesCallback) !== "function") throw new Error(                                         'succesCallback must be a function !');
   $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: '/actions.php',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        error: function(resp){ error.html(JSON.stringify(this)); },
        success: function(resp){
    //Вот она , но succesCallback аргумент resp не видит , ответ с сервера приходит нормально
                succesCallback.call(resp);
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: пример вызова processRequest({action:'delete',id:1},function(resp){alert(JSON.stringify(resp));})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вам call здесь вообще ? чем плохо

```
success: succesCallback
```

?

просто resp в вашем случае попадает в this функции successCallback:)

пример для осознания:

```
function test(arg) {
    console.log(this,arg); 
}

test.call([1,2,3],"argment here"); //[1,2,3],"argument here"
test.call([1,2,3]); //[1,2,3],undefined
```

то чего вы хотели добиться  должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
function processRequest(data, succesCallback) {
    if (typeof (data) !== "object") throw new Error('data must be in JSON format !');
    if (typeof (succesCallback) !== "function") throw new Error('succesCallback must be a function !');
    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: '/actions.php',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        error: function (resp) {
            error.html(JSON.stringify(this)); //тут у меня тоже сомнения, чему равен здесь this, читайте в сноске:
        },
        success: succesCallback
    });
}
```

---

> By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to $.ajax).

это значит что this в обработчике error будет равен $.extend($.ajaxSettings, #тут то что в фигурных скобочках в вызове ajax()#);  я как-то весьма не уверен что вы хотите именно этого вывода в обработчике ошибки.

У error: вот такие аргументы:

> `( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`

а вовсе не resp, resp в данном случае будет объектом [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR)

Answer (score 0):

как вариант:

```
function sendRequest( ctrl_loader, method, url, content, callback ) {
return $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: method,
    url: url,
    data: '{' + content + '}',
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $(ctrl_loader).show();
    }
}).done(function (data, status, xhr) {
    $(ctrl_loader).hide();
    if (callback)
        callback(xhr.status, data, request);
}).fail(function (data, status, xhr) {
    $(ctrl_loader).hide();
   });
```

Вызов:

```
sendRequest('.loader', 'POST', url, params, OnDetailShowSuccess);

function OnDetailShowSuccess(status, xml, request) {
...
}
```

Comment: en2012 , попробовал ,возвращает кучу каких-то обьектов , но это 100% не то,что пришло с ответа сервера ,есть еще какие-то варианты ?

Comment: Вам должен быть интересен только вот этот кусочек:
if (callback)       
 callback(...);
то есть на вход подается коллбэк функция и в нее передается управление.
Пример взят из рабочего проекта, где происходит вызов webservice и на вход приходит xml.

Comment: Да , вы правильно поняли , как я выяснил (внедрив ваш код в свой проект , возвращается экземпляр класса ajax ).Вот фрагмент ответа  - { readyState : 1 , getResponseHeader : function(e){var t;if(2===b){if(!c){c={};while(t=Tn.exec(a))c[t[1].toLowerCase()]=t[2]}t=c[e.toLowerCase()]}return null==t?null:t} , getAllResponseHeaders : function(){return 2===b?a:null} , setRequestHeader : function(e,t){var n=e.toLowerCase();return b||(e=v[n]=v[n]||e,y[e]=t),this} , ...
" Потому,что используется return $.ajax ,но данных ответа там 100% нет!

Comment: вот вы намудрили на ровном месте  :)

Comment: Благодарю за ответы , вопрос можно считать исчерпаным.